# Refresh web page taking too long time to load

Tags: performance, loading, html

we are developing single installer web application for that we are using following technologies.

> 1. wcf  - named pipe binding.
> 2. javascript, jquery.
> 3. signalR
> 4. mvc4

we have published the web application in iis 7.5 and os is windows 7.

here problem is while running the application 3 to 4 hours after that i can't do anything in my browser it is totally hanged.

few things I want to share to you,

> 1. few cases we are hide and show the HTML in dom instead of removing.
> 2. event handling - we are binding events but we don't check if the
>      event already mapped with that element.
> 3. signalR also one of my doubt. because it is pooling frequently.

right now if I get stuck with my browser I just restart my application pool.after that 
everything comes under my control.

so, can you please tell me why it is happening, might be my post is not clear but you 
can get some outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [use Chrome Profiler](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling) (In dev tools > profiles) to look for potential memory leaks. A common cause of memory leaks is forgetting to unregister event listeners when they are not required any more. And as you mention binding, I think it's a lead to follow.

Comment: Ok, our project we are using .On() event delegate. so, shall i use .Off() to remove all the 
event handler attach to the element?

Comment: That's exactly the idea. Remove each event listener as soon as it is not required any more. Or each one will create a memory leak and make you application less responsive.

Comment: now you can consider the scenario we are loading more than 100 controls at the start up. so, all the controls gets event handler  and we are using some model popup here we don't remove html element after close the popup simply hide and show the element. now approximately 200 controls loaded and all gets binding. now you can tell me the solution. is this right way to load all the controls ?

Comment: I can't. You must investigate using the profiler to identify the real problem. Only then you will be able to look for a solution. Otherwise you will try to fix/optimize something that is possibly not the source of your problem.